# encode/decode image with base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have created the multiple file (image) upload option. And I have encoded the image file and stored them in an array. 
I am trying to encode and decode an image. I am using the FileReader's readAsDataURL method to convert the image to base64.
Now I want to Convert the image(Original file) for the download option.

**My code is;**

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" multiple />
<div id="imgTest"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function encodeImageFileAsURL(index) {
        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
        index = index || 0;
        if (filesSelected.length > 0 && index < filesSelected.length) {
            var fileToLoad = filesSelected[index];

            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onloadend = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                newImage.src = srcData;

                document.getElementById("imgTest").appendChild(newImage);
                if (index < filesSelected.length) {
                    encodeImageFileAsURL(index + 1)
                }
                console.log(srcData);    
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);

            var sourceArray = new Array(); // put this before the function delaction 


                fileReader.onloadend = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                    var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                    sourceArray.push(srcData);

                    var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                    newImage.src = srcData;

                    document.getElementById("imgTest").appendChild(newImage);
                    if (index < filesSelected.length) {
                        encodeImageFileAsURL(index + 1)
                    }
                    alert( fileLoadedEvent.target.result);
                    var imgSrc= fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    console.log(imgSrc);
                    //console.log(sourceArray);
                    //alert( fileLoadedEvent.target.result);

                    }
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to Encode and Decode Uploaded image file(multiple) using input type ="File"

Comment: the base64 string you have is a string representation of your image file, but your image is in it. If you want to display it, you just have to create an HTMLImageElement (e.g through `new Image()`) and set its src to the dataURL.

Comment: That's what he has done in code above.

Comment: i done encode the image file and store it. Now i need to decode the base64 string to image..

Comment: @Kaiido,i already the display the image what the user uploaded. I encode the image using base64... I want to decode the base64 string this code itself.For example download option for uploaded file

Comment: That has non sense to me... You've got everything already : the Blob representation (available in `fileSelected`) and the dataURI version (used to show on page)). What do you want more ? BTW, if you are planning to use the download attribute of the AnchorElement, and only need the dataURI version to display these images,  you would be better using directly `URL.createObjectURL(yourBlob);`

Comment: Because i need to decode code itself for future use(if they top level want to download the file).... If it is possible

Comment: No please take some time to [edit] your question, make it clear what you are doing, what you want to do, and what doesn't work. Maybe ask someone to help you write in english since it doesn't seem to be your natural language (not mine either so I understand it may be difficult to write things clearly). Currently it is really hard to help you correctly. I'm pretty sure you don't need the FileReader, and I'm wondering why you would make the user download the file he just sent to your page...

Comment: thank u so much.  I have create the multiple file(Image ) option. I need to encode and decode the image file...